# ggplot: legend for a plot the combines bars / lines?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a empirical PDF + CDF combo I'd like to plot on the same panel.  `distro.df` has columns `pdf`, `cdf`, and `day`.  I'd like the pdf values to be plotted as bars, and the cdf as lines.  This does the trick for making the plot:

```
p <- ggplot(distro.df, aes(x=day))
p <- p + geom_bar(aes(y=pdf/max(pdf)), stat="identity", width=0.95, fill=fillCol)
p <- p + geom_line(aes(y=cdf))
p <- p + xlab("Day") + ylab("")
p <- p + theme_bw() + theme_update(panel.background = element_blank(), panel.border=element_blank())
```

However, I'm having trouble getting a legend to appear.  I'd like a line for the cdf and a filled block for the pdf.  I've tried various contortions with guides, but can't seem to get anything to appear.

Suggestions?

EDIT:

Per @Henrik's request: to make a suitable `distro.df` object:

```
df <- data.frame(day=0:10)
df$pdf <- runif(length(df$day))
df$pdf <- df$pdf / sum(df$pdf)
df$cdf <- cumsum(df$pdf)
```

Then the above to make the plot, then invoke `p` to see the plot.

Comment: @Henrik code to produce a suitable `distro.df` for use with the ggplot commands added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This generally involves moving `fill` into `aes` and using it in both the `geom_bar` and `geom_line` layers.  In this case, you also need to add `show_guide = TRUE` to `geom_line`.

Once you have that, you just need to set the `fill` colors in `scale_fill_manual` so CDF doesn't have a fill color and use `override.aes` to do the same thing for the lines.  I didn't know what your fill color was, so I just used red.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=day)) +
    geom_bar(aes(y=pdf/max(pdf), fill = "PDF"), stat="identity", width=0.95) + 
    geom_line(aes(y=cdf, fill = "CDF"), show_guide = TRUE) + 
    xlab("Day") + ylab("") + 
    theme_bw() + 
    theme_update(panel.background = element_blank(), 
               panel.border=element_blank()) +
    scale_fill_manual(values = c(NA, "red"), 
                   breaks = c("PDF", "CDF"), 
                   name = element_blank(), 
                   guide = guide_legend(override.aes = list(linetype = c(0,1))))
```

Comment: Brilliant work, thanks; I think I'm going to stick with the approach I ended up at, but this perfectly answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

I'd still like a solution to the above (and will checkout @aosmith's answer), but I am currently going with a slightly different approach to eliminate the need to solve the problem:

```
  p <- ggplot(distro.df, aes(x=days, color=pdf, fill=pdf))
  p <- p + geom_bar(aes(y=pdf/max(pdf)), stat="identity", width=0.95)
  p <- p + geom_line(aes(y=cdf), color="black")
  p <- p + xlab("Day") + ylab("CDF")
  p <- p + theme_bw() + theme_update(panel.background = element_blank(), panel.border=element_blank())
  p
```

This also has the advantage of displaying some of the previously missing information, namely the PDF values.